# Embed Json file in project

Tags: haxe

In AS3 I could embed a Json file as follows:

```
[Embed(source = "controllers.json", mimeType='application/octet-stream')]
private static const JSON_CONTROLLERS:Class;
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Haxe?

If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using OpenFL, there's two options:

- use `@:file` metadata:

  ```
  @:file("controllers.json")
  class JsonControllers extends openfl.utils.ByteArray.ByteArrayData {}

  class Main extends openfl.display.Sprite {
      public function new() {
          super();
          trace(new JsonControllers());
      }
  }
  ```

  You can also do this with pure Haxe, but only on the swf target. OpenFL makes this work on all targets.
- use `openfl.Assets`:

  Include an assets folder in your `project.xml` / `application.xml` file:

  ```
  <assets path="assets" />
  ```

  Access the file contents:

  ```
  trace(openfl.Assets.getText("assets/controllers.json"));
  ```

With pure Haxe, you'd probably want to use `-resource` - check the [Haxe Manual](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-resources.html) for a usage example.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Gama11's solutions, there is another option: use macros! ;)

The [compiletime](http://lib.haxe.org/p/compiletime) haxelib has an exact macro function that reads a JSON file as an object in compile-time:

```
var jsonObject = CompileTime.parseJsonFile("test.json");
```

The [source code of `parseJsonFile`](https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime/blob/2.6.0/src/CompileTime.hx#L65-L71) is very simple, and I recommend reading it to learn how Haxe macros work. For easy reference, the relevant parts are pasted here:

```
macro public static function parseJsonFile(path:String):ExprOf<{}> {
    var content = loadFileAsString(path);
    var obj = try Json.parse(content) catch (e:Dynamic) {
        haxe.macro.Context.error('Json from $path failed to validate: $e', Context.currentPos());
    }
    return toExpr(obj);
}

static function loadFileAsString(path:String) {
    try {
        var p = Context.resolvePath(path);
        Context.registerModuleDependency(Context.getLocalModule(),p);
        return sys.io.File.getContent(p);
    }
    catch(e:Dynamic) {
        return haxe.macro.Context.error('Failed to load file $path: $e', Context.currentPos());
    }
}

static function toExpr(v:Dynamic) {
    return Context.makeExpr(v, Context.currentPos());
}
```